# Given a blob of text (that is a complete html page) return all email(s) present

Tags: c#, regex

Okay so this is NOT my code, I just inherited it. Seems it has an obvious bug that it will only return the first email despite being called "GetEmails". My main concern is actually that it takes **forever** on some pages. The regex looks over complicated, but regex are something I have never really 'got into' hence posting it here:

```
public string GetEmails(string text)
{
    try
    {
        const string MatchEmailPattern =
       @"(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
       + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
         + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
       + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})";
        Regex rx = new Regex(MatchEmailPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        // Find matches.
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
        // Report the number of matches found.
        int noOfMatches = matches.Count;
        // Report on each match.

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            return match.Value.ToString();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CLog.LogMessage(string.Format("{0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
    }
    return null;

}
```

Comment: [Broken code](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3650) is off-topic for this site. Please [follow the tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Do you have special requirements for the email address matching, or it can be any possible email address?

Comment: It gets to the first match and returns.  return match.Value.ToString();

Comment: Email regex is such a common request that there are plenty of good ones online.

Comment: For email regex there is: `(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])` suggested from http://emailregex.com/

Comment: Very good I have learned from downvotes not to post simple things in attempt to free outsource when I could have done myself.

Answer (score 3):

Your are returning string
And you are returning only the first string

```
return match.Value.ToString();
```

I suspect you want to return an IEnumerable

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetEmails(string text)
{
    try
    {
        const string MatchEmailPattern =
              @"(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
            + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
            + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
            + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})";
        Regex rx = new Regex(MatchEmailPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        // Find matches.
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
        // Report on each match.
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            yield return match.Value.ToString();
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CLog.LogMessage(string.Format("{0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking as a fact that your method returns null in case of nothing found, please read the 1st solution. Otherwise suggested 2nd solution.

**1st solution**

You should have a list declared before the loop as:

```
List<string> emails = new List<string>();
```

And the loop should fill in this list:

```
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    emails.Add(match.Value.ToString());
}
```

And after the loop, just return the list:

```
return emails;
```

The rest should remain as they are.

```
public List<string> GetEmails(string text)
{
    try
    {
        const string MatchEmailPattern =
            @"(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
            + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
            + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
            + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})";
        Regex rx = new Regex(MatchEmailPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        // Find matches.
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
        // Report the number of matches found.
        int noOfMatches = matches.Count;
        // Report on each match.
        List<string> emails = new List<string>();
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            emails.Add(match.Value.ToString());
        }
        return emails;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CLog.LogMessage(string.Format("{0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
    }
    return null;
}
```

**2nd solution**

I would suggest that you give a solution returning an empty list in case of nothing found.
The differences in the code are:

- you return only once (better maintainable structure), and
- the returned value cannot be null so you will not have to check for nullability in the calling code.

The code should be like:

```
public List<string> GetEmails(string text)
{
    List<string> emails = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        const string MatchEmailPattern =
            @"(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
            + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
            + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
            + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})";
        Regex rx = new Regex(MatchEmailPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        // Find matches.
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
        // Report the number of matches found.
        int noOfMatches = matches.Count;
        // Report on each match.
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            emails.Add(match.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CLog.LogMessage(string.Format("{0} {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace));
    }
    return emails;
}
```

Comment: The return type on the function is still `string`, not `IEnumerable<string>`.  Is the client code expecting a delimited string containing all the addresses or did it never really work?  `noOfMatches` says, that it reports the number of matches found but is never used. Remove?

Comment: @AlanT this is true, I forgot to change the return type. I edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, so the regex is okay as it is?

Comment: @Darren Sorry, I only reviewed the single email return issue.